# PHPWord and ListItemRun, reset numbering

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PhpWord library for generating docx files.

In most cases I need to generate this file from HTML, so if I want to generate numeric list I need to use

```
$section->addListItemRun();
```

So if I generate two lists in the document I'm expecting result

```
1.Item 1
2.Item 2
3.Item 3

Some text here

1.Item 1
2.Item 2
3.Item 3
```

But I'm getting

```
1.Item 1
2.Item 2
3.Item 3

Some text here

4.Item 1
5.Item 2
6.Item 3
```

Does anybody know how I can reset numbering?

Another question, this library can add footnotes with this method

```
$section->addFootnote();
```

Can I change the label of the footnote?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the behavior in word. Not the document.
but you can hack with create unique list name

```
    $n = 1;
    foreach ($lists as $list) {
        // Hack to reset lists
        $listFormat = $phpWord->addNumberingStyle(
            'multilevel-'.$n,
            array('type' => 'multilevel', 'levels' => array(
                    array('format' => 'decimal', 'text' => '%1.', 'left' => 720, 'hanging' => 360, 'tabPos' => 720)                    
                )
            )
        );
        $section->addText(htmlspecialchars('Multilevel list.'));
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item I'), 0, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item I.a'), 1, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item I.b'), 1, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item II'), 0, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item II.a'), 1, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addListItem(htmlspecialchars('List Item III'), 0, null, 'multilevel-'.$n);
        $section->addTextBreak(2);
        $n++;
    }
```